Counting outgoing links connected to a node
I've a large linear shape and I need to find all nodes with class >=3 connected to at least two outgoing links.
It's actually a sewage graph, I'm trying to identify sewer dividers.
I have read these usefuls links but I'm not so much into Python to alter the code to make it work for me:
Counting number of lines connected to point?
Counting total number of other link ends link is connected to in QGIS?
I made an attempt in qgis with the script here described:  Counting number of lines connected to point? . But I'm unable to get past this point:
def pairs(list):
    '''generator to iterate over pairs in a list '''
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        yield list[i-1], list[i]

import networkx as nx 

# select the polyline layer
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
# create a Graph
G = nx.Graph()
# add the nodes and the edges to the Graph = segment point i -> point i+1
for features in layer.getFeatures():
    segment = features.geometry().asPolyline()
# add the two end points of a segment as two nodes and an edge (point1 -> point2) to the Graph
    for seg_start, seg_end in pairs(segment):
        G.add_edges_from([(seg_start, seg_end)])       

When I start the part where I need to print the nodes I get a generic syntax error. Any advice?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, this isn't focused enough for answer (you need to choose a platform and make an attempt). The good news is that Python is the world's easiest computer language to learn.

I made an attempt in qgis with the script here described:

Please include the error (as formatted text, not a screenshot), otherwise it makes it difficult for readers to know what the problem is.

'Generic syntax error'?  Add an error handler to pin down the line throwing the error?

This should work better on a large dataset:

Use Geometry by expression to create small polygons at each line's start point:
buffer(start_point($geometry),1)

Create a spatial index on the output

Create a spatial index on the line layer

Join attributes by location (summary) with the indexed line layer as "Join to features in" layer, and the indexed geometry by expression layer as "By comparing to" layer. Count as statistics.




I've both pipes ingoing and outgoing the manhole. Is there a way to identify and count only the outgoing pipes?

That is what the query does. If a line starts at a point, it is counted. Make sure you are using a projected coordinate system so the distance units are for example in meters and not degrees

This worked! A very smooth way!

I can make it work with small portion of my dataset but It get stuck with the whole. Do you think it's possibile to works on "manholes" and "pipes" on a DBmanager like access?

Virtual layers can be very slow. I've posted a different solution. <10 s for ~200 k lines and points. If you want to use SQL you can import your data to a PostgreSQL+PostGIS database and it will be a lot faster than virtual layers

Thank you @BERA, I've trying the new solution: in the point 4 we "join to features in" in the line layer (intersecting?) counting wich field? I don't see starting point in the line layer and also i get a line output. How do you get the result with outgoing count with this method?
